# GPT adverts not displaying [300,600] size

Tags: jquery, ads, adsense, google-dfp

In my site I am displaying ads using GPT.

The following code displays an advert:

```
 googletag.defineSlot('/1234/test', [300, 250], 'div1').addService(googletag.pubads());
```

But following code is not working:

```
 googletag.defineSlot('/1234/test', [300, 600], 'div1').addService(googletag.pubads());
```

Display divs:

```
 <div id="div1">
        <script type="text/javascript">
          googletag.display("div1");
        </script>
      </div>
```

How to display both sizes ad in slot?

I also tried:

```
googletag.defineSlot('/1234/test', [[300, 600],[300,250]], 'div1').addService(googletag.pubads());
```

but no use.

Answer (score 0):

GPT takes both [[300,600]] and [300,600] formats. That's not the reason why it doesn't work for you. Since [300,250] works for you, it's most likely caused by incorrect setup in doubleclick, such as no 300x600 creatives were targeted for the ad code you use.